# How to create a sub dictionary by random sample from the larger dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, iterator

I have one larger dictionary as below(Large_dict). I wanted to create a data frame from all possible values from the dictionary. I tried looping using for loop with iteration but it takes time to create dataframe.

Hence i am trying to create a sub dictionary (random sample of values ) from the larger dictionary to create a smaller dataframe from the all possible values from the smaller dictionary then append all the smaller data frame to create one final larger dataframe.

How to create a sub dictionary by random sample (3 values each key ) from the larger dictionary

```
   Large_dict= {
        "A":[0,1,.....215],
        "B":[4,5,.....100],
        "C":[0,1,......130],
        "D":[0,1,........235], 
           ......... 
        "Y":[0,1,........50],
        "Z":[0,1,........535]}
    
    Small_dict = { "A":[0,13,25],
        "B":[10,20,30],
        "C":[0,1,60],
        "D":[0,1,35], 
           ......... 
        "Y":[0,1,50],
    
        "Z":[0,35,100]}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`random.sample`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.sample) to choose 3 (in this case) from each of the sublists within a dict comprehension

```
>>> import random
>>> values = list(range(50))
>>> large = {'A': values, 'B': values, 'C': values}
>>> {k:random.sample(v, 3) for k,v in large.items()}
{'A': [22, 44, 45], 'B': [22, 0, 49], 'C': [23, 14, 32]}
```